# Excel formula that would look-up for values from certain sheets in the workbook

Tags: excel

I would just like to ask how can i copy and paste formulas that would have a continuous count. In my case, I have this formula "='X11M IPDM'!$D$23" located in cell E8, I would like to copy it to cell F8 and wanted to have a formula of "='X11M IPDM'!$J$23" because when I do the normal copy and pasting, the one that would reflect to cell F8 is the same with the one cell E8 since it has a "$". I would like to have a formula that could be dragged into the next cells. I hope somebody can help me. It would be of great help. Thanks.

Comment: If you drag it right a column, do you *always* want to increase the `$D$23` part by 6 columns? So if you put it in `F8`, it's `...$J$23`, and in `G8`, it's `...$P$23`, put in `H8`, it's `...$V$23`, etc.?

Comment: Yes, I want it to increase by 6 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter the following fomrula in `Cell E8`

```
=OFFSET('X11M IPDM'!$D$23,0,(COLUMNS($A:A)-1)*6)
```

then drag formula across to right as required. After dragging across this will get the results from `Cells D23, J23, P23, V23, AB23, ...`

***Note :*** `OFFSET` is a volatile function. For details on volatile function see [this](http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsi.htm).

Comment: Thank you so much. It helped a lot.

Comment: Nice thinking with `OFFSET()`...I was starting to do something with `INDIRECT()` but this is a more elegant solution I think.